# Adjoint of Equivalence Functors

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent categories. Then there exist functors $F: A \rightarrow B$ and $G: B \rightarrow A$ such that $F \circ G \cong 1$ and $G \circ F \cong 1$. 
I am trying to show that $G$ is a left and right adjoint of $F$ (Actually, the problem states that these functors have left and right adjoints, but I think that these are the correct adjoints).

I have been trying to work with the definition of adjunction that two functors are adjoint when $B(F(A), B) \cong A(A, G(B))$. I haven't been able to work out isomorphism is that would show that these two fuctors are adjoint. How should I proceed?

Comment: I just want to emphasize a subtlety here : even if indeed $F$ and $G$ are adjoint, the natural isos $FG\simeq 1$ and $GF\simeq 1$ that show that there are equivalences need not be the unit and counit of the adjunction. The [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+equivalence) explains that you can keep one of them, but the other one might need to be adjusted.

Comment: Does this affect the answer given by @Long? His answer seems to avoid considerations of the unit and couunit.

Comment: No it does not, the answer seems good to me. In fact, Long's answer inscribes in this remark as follow: it shows that $F$ is left adjoint to $G$ and keep the natural iso $1 \overset \simeq \to GF$ to be the unit; so it will be the counit that might not be exactly the isos $FG\overset \simeq \to 1$ that we have.  (This is very understandable as this natural iso does not play any role in Long's proof.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(Fa,b) \simeq (GFa,Gb) \simeq (a,Gb)$
The first bijection is due to $G$ being a category equivalence and the second is via composing with the natural transformation $Id \to GF $.

Comment: Does the first bijection follow from the fact that $G$ is full?

Comment: @Topos $G$ being a functor only gives you a function $(Fa,b)\to (GFa,Gb)$. This will be a bijection if and only if $G$ is full and faithful.

Comment: @Long How would I show that this isomorphism is natural in $A$ and $B$ though? Don't I also need to show that these functors are adjoint?

Comment: @Topos by definition of naturality; it is quite straight forward. First show the left bijection is natural, then show it for the right. Adjointness is the consequence of the naturality of the bijection - by definition...

Comment: @Long I'm really new to category theory, so it's not as simple as you'd think for me. Could you show me how to start it off?

Comment: How are you learning category theory? Do you have some math background?

Comment: Yes, I have a standard undergrad background (analysis, algebra, etc.), but I am finding category theory to be very abstract, and have very little intuition about all of the new concepts I am encountering (e.g. functors, natural transformations). I am trying to work through it, but keep getting stuck. I can't find many examples of how to work through a problem

Comment: join me in chat.stackexchange.com/